# Powershell Cmdlet to remove a statically configured DNS addresses from a network adapter

Tags: windows, powershell, netsh

I am trying to remove a statically configured DNS address from a network adapter.I can see that an equivalent netsh command is present :
`netsh interface ipv6 delete dns <adaptername> all` 
but I am required to do this operation using powershell cmdlets. Currently I haven't found any reference which talks about this. Most of the threads point me to the DNSServer module but all I require is to remove the DNS configured in my client machine. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the DNS server addresses using the `Set-DnsClientServerAddress` cmdlet, here is an example:

```
get-netadapter "Ethernet" | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ResetServerAddresses
```