AZ CLI runs very slow after a while
I'm experiencing inconsistent slow speeds with the Azure CLI (az-cli). Sometimes commands execute in less than 10 seconds, but at other times, the CLI seems to lock into a state of slowness (80+ seconds for a simple query).
This usually occurs after I've been using it for a while or when I have multiple terminal windows open and I've used Az CLI in at least two of them.
For example, when I run the following command:
az --version --debug

I see the following output after 80+ seconds:
az --version --debug
cli.knack.log: File logging enabled - writing logs to 'C:\Users\localuser\.azure\logs'.
cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['--version', '--debug']
cli.knack.cli: __init__ debug log:
Enable color in terminal.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PreExecute []
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): raw.githubusercontent.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool: https://raw.githubusercontent.com:443 "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Connectivity check: 4.057321899999806 sec
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): raw.githubusercontent.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool: https://raw.githubusercontent.com:443 "GET /Azure/azure-cli/main/src/azure-cli-core/setup.py HTTP/1.1" 200 1350
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): raw.githubusercontent.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool: https://raw.githubusercontent.com:443 "GET /Azure/azure-cli/main/src/azure-cli-telemetry/setup.py HTTP/1.1" 200 680
azure-cli                         2.65.0

core                              2.65.0
telemetry                          1.1.0

Extensions:
account                            0.2.5
automation                       1.0.0b1
azure-devops                       1.0.1
init                               0.1.0
next                               0.1.3

Dependencies:
msal                              1.31.0
azure-mgmt-resource               23.1.1

Python location 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\localuser\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.11.8 (tags/v3.11.8:db85d51, Feb  6 2024, 22:03:32) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x000002CAA0E1C360>]
cli.__main__: Command ran in 84.876 seconds (init: 0.211, invoke: 84.665)

Are these execution times normal? What might be causing this intermittent slowness?
Update: 2024-10-25
After reinstalling az-cli, the problem went away but it came back. What I've observed is that connecting and disconnecting the Ethernet cable solves the issue. But I don't have a permanent solution.

Have you tried clearing the cache before execution. @Daniel M.

I tried az cache purge and tried different versions of az-cli up to no avail. Will also try to uninstall removing all traces of az-cli and reinstall again to see if problem persists. @Jahnavi

Also check if the system is overloaded and remove unused configurations from ./azure @Daniel M.

The inconsistent slowness behavior with the Azure CLI could be a temporary issue with the CLI or windows environment. Windows Defender also makes things work slow in an environment sometimes.
Check below reasons to resolve it.
Firstly, the execution process of CLI commands can be slow if there is a bad network connection when it tries to connect with the external resources like raw.githubusercontentas I can see in your logs. So, check the connection has been established and accessed properly.
Try using the ping command to test network latency.
Also, refer the given blog to do speed tests as given in detailed.
Reference: Blog
When we use the --debug parameter, by default it takes a longer time than usual as it retrieves the complete logging information. If still the issue persists with it, avoid using it for a while until the CLI executions gets quick.
Usually, Az CLI collects all the telemetry data. This can also lead to slow execution, mainly when there is a network issue while trying to send telemetry data.
Disable it with below configuration command for time being and check the execution time.
az config set core.collect_telemetry=False
Refer MSDoc for setting the configuration according to the requirement and performance.
Also verify the installed extensions as it also might be causing the slowness sometimes. Check the extension list with az extension list and remove the conflicted extension if needed.
Using az cache purge also helps to resolve the issue in this kind of scenario as you already tried.
Check the CLI version and upgrade it with az upgrade to the latest release to avoid the performance issues.
I have checked my version with the az --version --debug and it was executed within fraction of seconds without any issues.


If still the issue persists, try unchecking the updates by using
--no-check-updates flag to avoid the unnecessary updates as it makes system running slow.

I disabled core.collect_telemetry, rebooted and tried several times to run az --version --debug --no-check-updates verifying it runs in under 0.8 seconds at all times. However after some time the issue comes back again. I will update with any findings.

Have you tried reinstalling the Azure CLI? @DanielM.

Deleted every extension, reinstalled Azure CLI. Now az --version runs in less than 0.3 seconds. I also reset my DNS configuration (just in case) using this command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465376/20765573
